# Excel file in OneDrive has conflicts, even though it's only updated from the phone

Tags: onedrive, office-hub

I have an Excel file in OneDrive that I update every few days, always from my phone. However, sometimes when I try to save, Excel says `Can't upload, A conflict occurred...`.

Then I have to resolve the conflict:

- Open location
- File says `Couldn't upload`. Long-tap file -> view status
- Now it says `Upload status - there's a conflict...`. Last update successful is current time, Last update attempted also current time (uncertain, will check next time it happens).
- Tap `Resolve`, choose `Replace item on server`, tap `Refresh copy`
- Now file is uploaded properly.

Version history in OneDrive doesn't show any funny version updates.

I understand that if I'd updated the file from a PC, I'd get a conflict. But I don't, so why do I get these conflicts?

Comment: I had a similar problem. It was because I use to loss the 3G connection in that particular venue. Sometimes it says another person is editing and sometimes something related to authentication mode. I solved this problem going to Office Hub, SkyDrive and find the file there. I wait to SkyDrive to sync and open the file. It open the local copy and looks like it fix the problem in my case (appear "downloaded a minute ago" instead of "can't upload".

Comment: Often have the "Couldn't upload" issue when changing a Excel file on my Windows Phone (in sync before change!).

Even I try to resolve it the result remains "Couldn't upload" ... Have to try the Upload/Resolve (replace item on server) several times until it works ... The problem is, that "Couldn't upload" doesn't say WHY ... Connection issue? Connection works ... Other issues....?

Answer (score 1):

Try these few troubleshooting points:

- Check for updates for 'Excel Mobile' and 'OneDrive' from the store. Finally also make sure your phone OS is up to date from going into 'Settings > Update and Security > Phone update.'
- Try downloading the file from OneDrive to your PC. Create a new Excel file locally. Select everything using 'Ctrl+A' and copy them 'Ctrl+C'. Paste it in the first cell on the new file using 'Ctrl+V' and rename that file according to your wish. Upload the new file and delete the old one.

Do these points help you correct this issue? If yes, give me an upvote! 
If they do not work, comment below, I've got more points for troubleshooting at an higher level.

Comment: I no longer have a Windows Phone, so I can't test. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this question was asked in 2013. But why does it float on top of the forum?

Comment: @SagnikPal Looks like it was [bumped to the top](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/194308), most likely by the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/194308) as part of its effort to bring more attention to unanswered questions.

Comment: @Jonathan, mind marking the question as answered?